# Signature_invalid error from oAuth while querying for Google Request Token in IOS

Tags: ios, oauth

I'm using oAuth to get request Token for unregistered installed app for "latitude" scope of google, i'm getting the response string as

```
signature_invalid
base_string:GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetRequestToken&oauth_consumer_key%3Danonymous%26oauth_nonce%3D1D759072-DB2B-4E21-AA23-67CADF98C14A%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1306734462%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Flatitude%26xoauth_displayname%3DTaj%2520Vivanta
```

The code i used to get request token is as follows

```
    OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"anonymous" secret:@"anonymous"]; 
    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url consumer: consumer token:token realm:nil signatureProvider: nil] autorelease];
    if (!request) return;
    [request setOAuthParameterName:@"scope" withValue:[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/latitude" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setOAuthParameterName:@"xoauth_displayname" withValue:@"Taj Vivanta"];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[[OADataFetcher alloc] init] autorelease];    
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest: request delegate: self didFinishSelector: success didFailSelector: fail];
```

Please help me to fix this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As clearly suggested by google [Document](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#SigningOAuth) the scope and xoauth_displayname parameters should in the URL but in the above code i was  placing these parameters in the request header.